# My Mac app package is working only after restarting my system after installation

Tags: macos

I have built a package of my mac app and exported it.but it is working only after restarting my system after installation. I am unable to find the solution for what is the differnce in environment of before restarting and after restarting.If i can get this i can provide that environment after installation instead of restarting my whole system....

Comment: That's a strange issue, however I doubt anyone can help without more info.  Are there any relevant messages in `Console.app`?  Do you log errors to a log file?  Can you debug the app?

Comment: Actually we used Apple scripts in this app.we called them in IBActions. May be i feel problem is here, we need to add some configurations inorder to use apple scripts. But unable to figure exact problem

Comment: If you don't keep log files then you have no hope of knowing when errors occur.  Integrate CocoaLumberjack and start logging errors to file otherwise you will spent eternity *guessing* what's wrong.

Comment: App is working very properly in xcode environment. but once we packaged and exported it out the problem occured.we need to restart system

Comment: It's anyone's guess.  That's why you need to add logging to a file you can look at (and customers can provide you when they have runtime problems).  There is not enough information to resolve your problem.

Comment: yeah we are checking logs.. but couldn't debug the issue

Comment: And i also observed another issue that after creating package and installing our apple script is running with privillages but shell script written in it is not getting hit.can any one help me what settings i need to do to develop an environment for my shell script to get hit without restarting system....